# Not sure how to template object of arrays using Backbone and Underscore templates

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a collection where the data is returned looking like:

```
{
  "departments": ["Customer Support", "Marketing"],
  "classes": ["Planning", "Drawing"]
}
```

I'm not overly sure how to use underscore template loops to output each of the departments, right now I'm using `._each` but my output is `object Object`. Can anyone advise how to resolve this?

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/aatc70Lo/7/

**Template**

```
<script type="text/template" class="js-department">
    <select>
        <% _.each(departments, function(department) { %>
            <option value="<% department %>"><% department %></option>
        <% }) %>
    </select>
</script>
```

**JS**

```
var Department = Backbone.Model.extend();

var Departments = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Department,
    parse: function(response) {
        return response;
    }
});

var DepartmentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: '.js-department',

    initialize: function() {
        console.log('DepartmentView::initialize', this.collection.toJSON());
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html( this.template( this.collection.toJSON() ) );
    }
});

var departments = new Departments({
  "departments": ["Customer Support", "Marketing"]
}, {parse:true});

var departmentView = new DepartmentView({
    collection: departments
});

document.body.innerHTML = departmentView;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are not even calling `render()`, so your template is never even executed, and the `object Object` output has nothing to do to your template.
2. After you run `render()` you will realize
   `template: '.js-department'`
   doesn't work, because it is not Marionette, and Backbone will not compile the html by a selector for you. So you will replace it with something like this:
   `template: _.template($('.js-department').html())`
3. Then you will have to realize `this.collection` is an array, that only has one item, so if you just want to render that first item, you will send to it to template:
   `this.$el.html( this.template( this.collection.first().toJSON() ) );`
4. Then you will have to realize `departmentView` is a Backbone.View instance object, and isn't html itself. It has the `el` property which is the DOM element of this view instance, and `$el` property, which is the same DOM element wrapped with jQuery.
5. `document.body.innerHTML = departmentView.el` still will not work, because `innerHTML` expects a string. So you could instead do something like
   `document.body.appendChild( departmentView.el );` or
   `departmentView.$el.appendTo( document.body );` with jquery.
   (For the last one to work `render` must `return this`)

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yuraji/zuv01arh/